# Internet Explorer control (or other) rendered onto a directdraw surface

Tags: c++, browser, directdraw

I'm tasked with modifying an existing c++ codebase which uses directdraw for its UI. Is it possible to make use of a browser control that renders onto one of the (existing) directdraw surfaces? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to get started? (or an alternative approach)

Regards all,

Jaime

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Awesomium](http://princeofcode.com/awesomium.php).

Comment: Thanks, but I think that is overkill for what I aim to achieve. This will be a static display. I'd much prefer to do this without having closed source third party components. Open source is fine, as is writing the thing myself.